# The simplest way of get an emerging modal window

Tags: 7, javascript, chaos-tool-suite

I want to open a modal emerging window, with some HTML on it and a close button. It should open when the user visits the page. What is the simplest way of doing that and what modules should I use? I have tried with CTools and a javascript (jQuery) emulation of click on a hidden link, but that gives me problems and seem so convoluted to me. Is there any simplest way?

Comment: is your theme bootstrap theme base?

Comment: No, it is based on Zend theme.

Comment: what is on modal( drupal form or just data) ?

Comment: The Drupal form itself.

Answer (score -2):

You can check one of the module:

1. [Splashify](https://www.drupal.org/project/splashify)
2. [Pop-up announcement](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_announcement)
3. [Popup On Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_onload)

Comment: Sorry, but you are introducing modules which have aroud 1,000 downloads. CTools, on the other hand, has almost 1,000,000 downloads. I do not see the adventage of adding another module when I already use CTools. I would expect some behaviour or something to acomplish the task.